# (T) "$C \vDash \phi$" vs $C \vDash \phi$

Tags: set-theory

I am reading some notes on set theory, and I have encountered notations like :

(T) "$C \vDash \phi$" where $T$ is a theorie, $\phi$ is a formula and $C$ is a set. This means that $T \vdash \phi^C$ meaning that the theory $T$ proves the relativisation of $\phi$ to $C$

I don't really understand how this relates to $C \vDash \phi$ which means that $C$ is a model for the theory $\phi$. It is almost the same notation but they don't seem to be equivalent already because there is a reference to some theory $T$ in the first case.

Comment: I would write the first statement as $T\vdash C\models \phi$ or $T\vdash\mbox{``}C\models\phi\mbox{''}$ or $T\vdash(C\models\phi)$. The first suggestion looks strange. Unless it is in a text where you see things like "**Theorem ($T$).** $\phi$''.

Comment: Can you give a link to the notes?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am reading the book from Kenneth & Kunen on [set theory](http://blacaman.tripod.com/cursos/pdf/2012-2_0941.pdf). An example would be $WF$ models $ZF$ which means $ZF^- \vdash (ZF)^{WF}$ which I don't really know how to relate to the other notion of $WF \vDash ZF$ which means $WF$ is a model for $ZF$ .